# workout on json output

Tags: jquery, json

Dear all i m getting the below output

```
["images\/zara\/shoes\/thumbnail\/1.png","images\/zara\/shoes\/thumbnail\/2.png"]
```

via this code

```
    $imgurl=array();
$i=0;
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
    //Fetch rows
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

        $imgurl[$i]=$row['imgurl'];
        //echo "<img src='$imgurl[$i]' />";
        $i+=1;
        }
}
echo json_encode($imgurl);
```

and now at jquery end i m grabbing this code and getting displayed but i want to operate a loop on the output  create new img tags and insert each image path in new img src""

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('ul.sub_menu a').click(function() {
    var txt = $(this).text();
        $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
        url: 'thegamer.php',
        data: {send_txt: txt},
        datatype:'json',
        success: function(data){
            $('#main-content').html(data);
            }   
        });
    });
});
```

any code will be usefull

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you need for success:

```
success: function(data) {
  // data contains an array of strings, each with the src for your img
  var maincontent = $('#main-content');
  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    var img = $('<img />');
    img.attr('src', data[i]);
    maincontent.append(img);
  }
}
```

Of course there are lots of other ways you could do the loop as well.

Here's an full example that populates main-content on document load:

```
  <html>
    <head>
      <script src="js/jquery.js" ></script>
      <script language="javascript">
      $(function() {
           var txt = "test";
           $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: 'data.json',
             data: {send_txt: txt},
             dataType:'json',
             success: function(data) {
                        var maincontent = $('#main-content');
                        for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                          var img = $('<img />');
                          img.attr('src', data[i]);
                          maincontent.append(img);
                        }
                      },
             error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(textStatus); }
            });
        });

      </script>
    </head>
  <body>
  <div id="main-content"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

By the way, I think your `datatype` variable in the ajax request should be `dataType`, with a capital T.

It's also *always* a good idea to provide an error function on ajax calls, otherwise it's very difficult to know if something is going wrong. My `data.json` contains the output string you provided above. Of course the image links are broken in my browser, but they will work for you if the images are in the right places.

Comment: What is the value of `data` in your success function?

Comment: at the top of my question plz watch it

Comment: In what way is it not working? Nothing displaying? Error appearing?

Comment: plz look at my question i have put up the output now how to loop that output ur code is giving this output at console with error                                                                                "NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://localhost/new/%3C"
<
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/new/!"
!
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/new/D"
D
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/new/Y"
Y
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/new/h"

L

Comment: That sounds very weird. Can you try the full example I've edited above, including creating a `data.json` just to be sure? I can't imagine where the NetworkError is coming from... ?

Comment: i change the datatype to dataType now it doesnt give any output there wa a typpo error but now it doesnt even give this output ["images\/zara\/shoes\/thumbnail\/1.png","images\/zara\/shoes\/thumbnail\/2.png"]